# Scala, Lift Setup

Tags: scala, mongodb, lift

I want to get into Scala and the lift framework, but since there is alot of confusion for me as a PHP programmer. So I got some questions to help me get started.

I want to setup a webserver that runs the lift framework with a Mongo DB backend where do I begin?
What is Apache Tomcat?
What is Jitty?
Is Comet an technology (protocol, design pattern?) or is it an project like Lift?

How can I setup Lift in Mac Os x as development enviroment, I understand I need Eclipse so I have downloaded it but what then? I don't understand how to install Scala.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Lift wiki](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/Getting_Started) has a lot of information to get you started, and I would encourage you to join the [mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/liftweb). Where you will find many answers to questions already asked and you can of course ask more :)

Best luck using lift!

Answer (score 0):

Try these series of tutorials http://blog.pboos.ch/2011/03/lift-tutorial-1-dev-environment-setup/